# Delete records Oracle before tests from Ruby, capybara and Cucumber. Please

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, cucumber, capybara

does anyone have an example of how to remove the records from the table before starting or after finishing the tests?

My tests are working perfectly fine and all that remains is to automatically remove the records in the table. If anyone has an example link I would be very happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the gem database_cleaner

see: https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner

Comment: It doesn't work for me, I need to remove records from a table in oracle.

Comment: Are you using ActiveRecord? If so then the database_cleaner-active_record gem should do the job.

Comment: Does it work with oracle too?

Comment: I tried this way https://github.com/rsim/ruby-plsql but I don't know how and where to pass the database connection parameters. Want to help me, I pay!.

Comment: I already installed the gems:  gem 'ruby-plsql' gem 'ruby-oci8', '~> 2.2', '>= 2.2.2' . In SQL Server . 
In SQL server I use TinyTDS but in oracle I don't know how to use.                                   module Conexao_BD
    def conexao_BD
      $client = TinyTds::Client.new username: 'gdxarl', password: 'WFM#02!', 
      host: 'vjuyt_pdbgh_dev.gabprivate10032.gablan.oraclevcn.com', port: '1521', 
      database: 'mendcall_PDB3_DEV', azure: false
    end

Comment: I can't help any further with this. I don't use Oracle myself. I'm pretty sure that people have used Oracle with ActiveRecord, and if thats the case then database cleaner should work with Oracle, because it works through ActiveRecord. You'll have to dig further yourself, or hope to get a better answer from someone else. Good luck :)

Comment: Hello, it worked here!!... I searched and found a solution.. Thank you

Comment: Great news! It would be good if you added an answer here about what you did to get things working. Would help others with same issue.

Comment: hello yes i will!!!.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution that worked!

```
1: install gems: 
gem 'execjs'
gem 'date'
gem 'ruby-oci8'
gem 'sequel'

require:
require 'execjs'
require 'date'
require 'oci8'
require 'sequel'

in the page (siteprism)  or step definitions
def delete_Inclusao
conn = OCI8.new('user', 'password','host:1521/services') conn.exec('table WHERE login = :1', 'xxxx')
conn.commit
end
```